# Fingerstyle - dead notes percussive technique help

Tags: technique, fingerstyle-guitar, percussion

Currently learning fingerstyle (acoustic), and learning "set fire to the rain (Adele)" by sungha jung.

Here is a link to the video of the song being played:

I cannot tell for the life of me exactly how he is creating this 'percussion' sound, slowing the video down it doesn't look like he's intentionally trying to mute any strings?. looking up part of a tab someone has made for this song an example would be this:
[image]

would this be what he's doing? it seems like a hell of a lot to manage to mute different specific strings every other beat for the entire song

(link to entire tab https://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/sungha-jung-set-fire-to-the-rain-tab-s89250)

Comment: He's probably using fingers 2, 3 & 4 for the slap, but it's hard to tell… because he's miming [cheating, as often happens in this type of video] :\ If you want to see it done expertly, listen to some John Mayer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DfQC5qHhbo [song proper comes in at about 1 min but he's always worth 6 minutes of your time]